# Причастный оборот между однородными членами и обобщающим словом

Tags: пунктуация

В тестах есть предложение "Лес, луга, простирающиеся на много километров — все озарилось радостным светом". Составители указывают, что в нём содержится пунктуационная ошибка, но отказываются пояснять, какая именно. То ли причастный оборот нужно обособлять перед тире, то ли тире и вовсе не нужно ставить. Поисковик не выдаёт об этом случае ничего полезного - всё сводится к стандартному перечислению правил об однородных членах и, отдельно, об обособленных определениях. Хочу узнать, как это предложение пишется на самом деле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Лес, луга, **простирающиеся на много километров,** — все озарилось радостным светом.*

[Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) (Розенталь):

6. Если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами предложения, то перед ним ставится **тире**: *Вся наигранная весёлость, самообладание, сдержанность — всё покинуло Титка в этот момент* (Ш.)...

**Причастный оборот,** отнесенный к однородным членам и расположенный после них, **обособляется** с двух сторон.

Это принцип **независимой постановки** знаков по разным правилам. Соответственно, в предложении используется сочетание запятой и тире.